# Apache Camel routing

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, integration

A short question about Apache Camel.
I have the following scenario, where my server receives jms messages and then transform to csv file and then insert DB.
For this purpose i have 2 beans:

- xml2csv
- insertDB

I use routing like:

```
    <route id="route1" errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler">
        <from uri="file://{someFolder1}}
            ?...
        <to uri="bean:xml2csv" />
        <log message="transformed to xml file" />
    </route>

    <route id="route2" errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler">
        <from uri="file://{{someFolder2}}
            ?...
        <to uri="direct:csvOnboardingChannel" />
    </route>

    <route id="csvOnboarding" errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler">
        <from uri="direct:csvOnboardingChannel" />
        <to uri="bean:insertDB" />
    </route>
```

When "route" a file from-to, is it move like a message? or putting the question different, does Apache Camel take a file, wrap it as a message and route it to a bean or a component?

Do I understand it correct or am in a wrong directation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Camel reads in the file's data and sends it as a message through the route to a bean. Might also be simpler as a single route, like so:

```
<route id="route1" errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler">
    <from uri="file://{someFolder1}}">
        <to uri="bean:xml2csv" />
        <to uri="bean:insertDB" />
</route>
```